# How to delete a appoiment from device calendar in windows phone8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

When I am trying to delete an event from device calender through my application it showing an error

**Error Message:**

> ```
> An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
> ```

Please look at below code that iam using for delete operation

```
 AppointmentStore appointmentStore = await AppointmentManager.RequestStoreAsync(AppointmentStoreAccessType.AppCalendarsReadWrite);
         AppointmentCalendar sysCal = await appointmentStore.GetAppointmentCalendarAsync(dCalendarID);
          await sysCal.DeleteAppointmentAsync(dCalendarEventID);
```

anyone have any idea about this please help me.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permissions to use the calendar? Look for `ID_CAP_APPOINTMENTS` in the application manifest file `WMAppManifest.xml`.